# Boost Error on Cuda generated VC++ solution (Error C2675)

Tags: boost, cuda, compiler-errors

I created a Cuda 5 project (VC++) in Visual Studio, and I want to use boost chrono API.  When I include `boost/chrono.hpp`, I have the following error:

```
Error   89  error C2675: unary '-' : 'T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a
 type acceptable to the predefined operator D:\StandaloneApp\Library\Vc\boost_1_52_0\boost\ratio\detail\mpl\abs.hpp
68  1   ThrustCompareSoaAndAos
```

The code block around line 68:

```
#if defined(BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_NESTED_VALUE_ARITHMETIC_2)
namespace aux {
template< typename T, T n > struct abs_wknd
{
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(T, value = (n < 0 ? -n : n));
    typedef integral_c<T,value> type; // line 68
};
}
#endif
```

What causes this error?

Comment: Could you post the code around line 68?

Comment: is this being included from a .cu file?

Comment: @alrikai: [This isn't my question, but I have the same issue.] Yes, this happens while compiling a .cu with nvcc. The same code compiles fine on Linux.

Comment: @shinjin It's interesting that it compiles on linux, the last time I had checked in with using boost and CUDA, you would have to sequester any boost stuff to cpp files, then compile your cpp files separately w/ your host compiler and your .cu files with nvcc, then link the two to prevent nvcc from getting stuck on certain boost constructs. The fact that it works on linux at all is surprising to me, but I guess nvcc is making progress with the template support

Answer (score 1):

I changed the line:
BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(T, value = (n < 0 ? -n : n));
to
BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(T, value = (n < 0 ? (n * -1) : n));

this complied.